# Restrict INSERT to specific value in given column for certain user

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a possibility, to restrict, that certain user can insert only specified value in some column?

For example table

```
test (id integer, value text)
```

and user 'restricted_user' could only INSERT `1` in column `id` (any in the other columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use Row Level Security:

```
ALTER TABLE test ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

GRANT INSERT ON test TO restricted_user;

CREATE POLICY restr_ins ON test
  FOR INSERT TO restricted_user
  WITH CHECK (id = 1);
```

You'd have to add appropriate policies for other users that are supposed to work with the table, else they can do nothing with the table.

Answer (score 1):

Row Level Security (as shown by Laurenz) is one option. Using a VIEW and  `with check option` is another solution:

```
create view restricted_test
as
select *
from test
where id = 1
with check option;
```

Then disallow inserts into the table directly:

```
revoke insert,update on test from restricted_user;
```

And only allow to insert into the view:

```
grant insert,update on restricted_test to restricted_user;
```